# Missing number, treated as zero - what did I read

Tags: errors

OK, guys I wanted to compile a simple thing that usually works and on the line:

```
[\sum\sub{\gamma \in \Delta}c\sub{\gamma}h\sub{\gamma}, x\sub{\alpha\sub{1}}] \equals 0
```

LaTeX says "missing number, treated as zero". Yeah, I have in my code before `\begin{document}` entire thing needed for this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\plus}{+}
\newcommand{\on}{^}
\newcommand{\minus}{-}
\newcommand{\equals}{=}
\newcommand{\sub}{_}
```

Can you please help me as this is my first time seeing such a message, and I did not find any similar references in questions about same message.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: I just did that. Turns out \ before [ is needed or Latex is going crazy

Comment: You fixed your issue already? You can delete question then

Comment: You have not provided an example, presumably the `[` is following `\\ ` so you need `\\{}` or `\\ \relax`  (not `\ `) so that it is not taken as optional argument.